# How does routes of Ruby On Rails know which controller to hit when we hit an url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

How ROR routes recognise which controller method to hit while we hit an url.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the official Rails guide?

Comment: `routes.rb` inside config folder says her which controller  she should use. 
`get 'login', to: 'sessions#new'` exactly does this: if you see `login` fragment. use `SessionsController`s `new` action/mehod.

Comment: you mean there is no mediator between routes and the perticular controller which we mentioned in routes.rb?

Comment: Take a look at `rake routes` when in a rails project

Comment: ofcourse there is - actiondispatch is the framework between this powerful routes dsl. https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a way to redirect incoming requests to controllers and actions. It replaces the mod_rewrite rules. Best of all, Rails' Routing works with any web server. Routes are defined in app/config/routes.rb.

Think of creating routes as drawing a map for your requests. The map tells them where to go based on some predefined pattern.

The routes.rb file defines the actions available in the applications and the type of action such as get, post, and patch.

**like:**
  get 'photos/:id' => 'photos#show', :defaults => { :format => 'jpg' }

the normalise value of above route is.

```
app: #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher:0x007fd05e0cf7e8
           @defaults={:format=>"jpg", :controller=>"photos", :action=>"show"},
           @glob_param=nil,
           @controller_class_names=#<ThreadSafe::Cache:0x007fd05e0cf7c0
           @backend={},
           @default_proc=nil>>
conditions: {:path_info=>"/photos/:id(.:format)", :required_defaults=>[:controller, :action], :request_method=>["GET"]}
requirements: {}
defaults: {:format=>"jpg", :controller=>"photos", :action=>"show"}
as: nil
anchor: true
```

Answer (score 3):

The official Ruby on Rails documentation explains this question in a thorough and understandable way:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html